# Changing index order of points within the same polygon

Tags: qgis, polygon, point-in-polygon

I am currently trying to get rid of a waterway that divides my polygon. The problem is that the points are part of the same polygon but are around 190 rows away for each other.

Is there a way to rearrange the point so that the points in the black circle are connected to each, same for the red circled points?

[image: The point are divided by a river]

[image: They are part of the same polygon]

Answer (score 2):

If your layer is a MultiPolygon layer it easy to join the two multiparts of your polygon just using the *Reshape Feature* tool combined with the *Merge Feature* tool (both in the Advanced Digitising Toolbar).

1. Reshape the edge of one of the parts to overlap the second part.
2. Select the two tarts that you want to join.
3. Use the merge tool to join them.

See attached images.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]